# detect if user hovers for period of time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, user-experience

I'm using this animate jQuery code:

```
                $('.tabs').hover(
                    function(){
                        $('#tabs-wrap').animate({marginTop: '+=147'}, 500);
                        $('.tabs li a').delay(250).animate({height: '150'}, 500);
                    },
                    function(){
                        $('.tabs li a').animate({height: '40'}, 500);
                        $('#tabs-wrap').delay(250).animate({marginTop: '-=147'}, 500);
                    }
                );
```

But is it possible to only start animating if the user has the mouse hovered for a certain amount of time (to stop the effect if the they just swipe the mouse of rather than intentionally activating it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin, basically it uses setTimeout to invoke the function after x millseconds, the timeout is cancelled if they user mouse outs.